# i cant show image from drawable in my app using JSON

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i did everything right to read my json data from assets (recipe.json) which contains

{"id":"1",
"name":"الوصفة 1",
"desc":"الوصفة 1",
"image":"R.drawable.image"}...

i loaded name and desc correctly in recyclerView but the image doesnt show using getIdentifier() ... this is my code

```
     private void addItemsFromJSON() {
        try {

            String jsonDataString = readJSONDataFromFile();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("recipes");



            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); ++i) {

                JSONObject itemObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = itemObj.getString("name");
                String desc = itemObj.getString("desc");
                String image = itemObj.getString("image");
                // get resource id by image name
                int resourceId =getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable",getPackageName());
                Recipe recipe = new Recipe(name, desc,resourceId);
                recipes.add(recipe);
            }

        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "addItemsFromJSON: ", e);
        }
    }
```

it shows the title and describtion but image is empty

Comment: are you sure you have implemented logic of resource parsing and Drawable setting into View in concrete ViewHolder implementation of your RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

Modify image name in the JSON like
    {"id":"1", "name":"image1", "desc":"Image Description", "image":"imageNameInTheDrawable"}
Get the drawable from the resources:

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject itemObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = itemObj.getString("name");
            String desc = itemObj.getString("desc");
            String imageName = itemObj.getString("image");
            // Get drawable by image name
         Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
              .getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe(name, desc,drawable);
            recipes.add(recipe);
        }
```

Comment: Ok Solved ... i didnt use drawable that you did , i just renamed the image to "image" because i was getting from drawable wrong name , Thank you